# Yii why this route does not match

Tags: yii, routes

I want to create simple routes for article routes but unsuccessfully. I have first route which should match regular expression and second like a slug route. Second one works well but the first one does not match nothing. What is wrong with this route?

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'article/<action: (index|view|delete|create|update)>' => 'article/<action>',
            'article/<slug>' => 'article/view'
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Did you tried to remove space after `action:`?

Comment: Thats it. Space was the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no space after `action:`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'article/<action:(index|view|delete|create|update)>' => 'article/<action>',
        'article/<slug>' => 'article/view'
    ],
],
```